# How do I remove an unwanted location from Modern UI Weather?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

How can I remove an unwanted weather location from the Modern UI Weather app in Windows 8?

For example, "London, England" is on the list, and I'm not currently interested in the weather there, how can I remove "London" from the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can remove a location anytime from the Modern UI Weather app, *except when the location is set as the default.*

You can never remove the default weather location in Modern UI Weather application. In this case, `London, England` happened to be the first weather location.

So, I had to set another place as the default location.

To set a location as the default location, first add the location, then go to the location's page.  Right-click, and select in the bottom, left hand corner: `Set as Default`. Then you can remove the other location(s) by going to their respective pages and, again, right-clicking, then `Remove`.

Answer (score -1):

Click on "add location" and what you already have to the right you can add or click the X to delete.